# setting chef hostname to nodename on/after bootstrap

Tags: linux, chef, cookbook

I do tests atm with Chef and I have a virtual machine which I'm cloning to generate new nodes. I do bootstrap with the knife command and the -N Parameter to give each host a nodename. The Problem is tough, that the hostname on the VM doesn't change and if I'm trying to bootstrap another client it fails because Chef has this node already signed up.
I did now try to set the hostname in my [base Role](https://github.com/opscode/cookbooks/tree/master/chef-client) with the [hostname](http://community.opscode.com/cookbooks/hostname) cookbok but when I run `chef-client` it gives me a:

```
---- Begin output of hostname @config[:chef_node_name] ----
STDOUT: 
STDERR: hostname: the specified hostname is invalid
---- End output of hostname @config[:chef_node_name] ----
Ran hostname @config[:chef_node_name] returned 1
```

The Attributes for the base Role are:

```
name "base"
description "Base role applied to all nodes"
override_attributes(
  "chef_client" => {
    "init_style" => "upstart",
    "server_url" => "http://chef.ws:4000"
    },
  "set_fqdn" => 
        "@config[:chef_node_name]"
)
run_list(
  "recipe[hostname]",
  "recipe[chef-client::delete_validation]",
  "recipe[chef-client::service]"
)
```

Do I have a syntax error here in the set_fqdn or is the @config variable simply not accessible on the node? Is there a better way to set the hostname to the nodename?

Comment: `"@config[:chef_node_name]"` should not have the double quotes. @config[:chef_node_name] is indeed an invalid hostname.

Comment: @Kyle this was just an example, I tried several approaches. It doesnt really matter tough, because ``@config`` isn't available in roles-files ;(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After so trial and error I'm quite sure the `@config` and `node` variables are not accessible in role files. My solution was to rewrite the hostname cookbook to look for an attribute `nodename_as_fqdn` and set it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The node name is accessible on the node running chef through the `node.name` accessor.

You can use the chef_hostname cookbook to set the hostname to the node name by putting this in your metadata.rb:

```
depends "chef_hostname"
```

And then setting the hostname like:

```
hostname node.name
```